# How can I access a method of a class from a generic method

Tags: java, generics, methods

I'm working on a tiny exercise java program that calculates *circle* and *square* (classes) area, that implements *surface* (interface) which has a method called *area()*. A requirement is that I have to implement a class called *SumArea* that has a **generic method called calcArea()** that receives *Circle circ[]* and *Square square[]* arrays and executes area calculation.

**Program structure:**

**->** UseSumArea.java (main method)
**->** Surface.java (interface)
**->** Square.java (class that implements Surface.java)
**->** Circle.java (class that implements Surface.java)
**->** SumArea.java (class that executes calcArea() method)

**UseSumArea.java**

```
public class UseSumArea {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Square square[] = { new Square(2.0), new Square(5.0) };
            Circle circ[] = { new Circle(3.0), new Circle(2.0) };
            Surface surf[] = new Surface[square.length + circ.length];
            surf[0] = square[0];
            surf[1] = square[1];
            surf[2] = circ[0];
            surf[3] = circ[1];
            SumArea sum = new SumArea();
            System.out.println("Square's sum area = " + sum.calcArea(square));
            System.out.println("Circle's sum area = " + sum.calcArea(circ));
            System.out.println("Surface's sum area = " + sum.calcArea(surf));
        }
    
    }
```

**Surface.java**

```
public interface Surface {
    public double area();
}
```

**Square.java**

```
public class Square implements Surface {

private double area;
private double side;

public Square(double l) {
    this.side = l;
    area();
}

@Override
public double area() {
    return this.area = (this.side)*(this.side);
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public double getSide() {
    return side;
}

public void setSide(double side) {
    this.side = side;
}

}
```

**Circle.java**

```
public class Circle implements Surface {

private double area;
private double radius;

public Circle (double r) {
    this.radius = r;
    area();
}

@Override
public double area() {
    return area = (((this.radius)*(this.radius))*(Math.PI));
}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public void setRadius(double raio) {
    this.raio = raio;
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

}
```

**SumArea.java**

```
public class SumArea {

private double area;

public <T> double calcArea(T[] t) { //generic method that receives Square and Circle arrays
    double arrayArea = 0;
    for (T a : t) {
        arrayArea = arrayArea+(a.area()); 
    }
    return this.area = arrayArea;
}
}
```

My doubt is over this SumArea's code snippet:

> *arrayArea= arrayArea+(**a.area()**);*

**How can I access the area() method of each Circle and Square objects inside this generic method?**

Comment: As an aside, `setArea` on Square and Circle is a terrible idea. The area should be a derived attribute that is calculated off of the side length or radius. With your design I can create a Square of side 4 and then set its area to 100. As long as I call `getArea()` and not `area()` (why have both?), the wrong area will be returned. Also, unless `setSide` and `setRadius` are required, I would get rid of them and make Square and Circle immutable (which is almost always better when possible). Finally, `l` is a terrible name for a variable. `this.side = l` and `this.side = 1` look too similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bound the type variable:

```
public <T extends Surface> double calcArea(T[] t) {
```

or just declare the parameter as an array of `Surface`s:

```
public double calcArea(Surface[] t) {
```

Note that the latter is preferable because generics and arrays don't play very nicely together. If you were to need to have a type variable for other reasons, it would be advisable to change to a `Collection`, or similar:

```
public <T extends Surface> double calcArea(Collection<T> t) {
```

(And, as a minor matter of preference, I would use `S` rather than `T` to name a type variable which extends `Surface`)

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem in regard to generic types is already addressed [by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71352521/17949945), I just want to add a suggestion related to the **class design**.

I think there is a bit of redundancy in how these classes were designed. You need to create an instance of `SumArea` in order to do the calculation. And the result of the last of the last `calcArea()` method call will be stored in this object (let's assume that this calculation is far more *complex* and *CPU-consuming*).

But do we really need to store somewhere else the value is already returned by the method? In this case, the idea to cash the history of calculations (as a single variable or as a collection of values) doesn't seem to be useful because it can't be reused without knowing *which objects* were involved in the calculation.

And without storing the result this method will not be bound to a state, i.e. it has to be **static**. And since interfaces can have static methods, instead of creating a utility class for that purpose it could be placed in the `Surface` interface. Like that.

```
public interface Surface {
    public double area();

    public static <T extends Surface> double calcArea(T[] t) { // generic method that receives Square and Circle arrays
        double arrayArea = 0;
        for (T a : t) {
            arrayArea += a.area();
        }
        return arrayArea;
    }
}
```

**Note** that static behavior declared in interfaces in contrast to classes could be invoked only by using the name of an interface:

```
System.out.println("Circle's sum area = " + Surface.calcArea(circ));
```

Also note that it makes sense for both classes to have a field `area` inside the classes `Circle` and `Square` only if other fields will be declared as **final**, i.e. they must be initialed only one during the object construction and setters become unnecessary.

In this case (assuming that `radius` has been declared as **final** and is being validated when assigned so that `reduce > 0`) method `area()` will look like this:

```
@Override
public double area() {
    if (area > 0) { // `0` is a default value for instance variables
        return area; // reusing already calculated value
    }
    return area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

And there mustn't be two methods `area()` and `getArea()` leave either one or another.